# Bar code reader showing encoded data

Tags: c#

I am using Smart SM850 bar code reader to detect a 13 digit bar code in my C# windows form application but it is showing the number in this format " @!!@#$%^&*(!& ".
Is there any way to get the string as it is in the bar code directly to the text box or any way to decode this encoded string. 
please guide me how to get its decoded form.

[The attached Picture is the 13 digit bar code i am trying to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZbz.png)

Comment: So with what code are you controlling the bar code reader?

Comment: It looks like it's at least differentiating between the lines, it's just choosing to output symbols instead of numbers. You could always do some tests to say "when it says '@', I know it means '2'", build that into a dictionary, and then run the output of your current method through the dictionary to get the real answer out.

Comment: i am not using any code for this.its a plug n play bar code reader, i am using it to detect the string directly in my textbox

Comment: We can help with code issues. If you have no code then your best option is to consult the manual that came with the bar code reader, or seek technical documents on the manufacturer's web site.

Answer (score 0):

```
2 112345 6789 17
@ !!@#$% ^&*( !&
```

Notice any pattern?  Type the number on the bar code while holding down the shift key.

I'm guessing you just need to set up a mapping table, or possibly add an offset value to the ASCII code for each character.  The translation is on your QWERTY keyboard:

```
!@#$%^&*()
1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the barcode reader simply emulates keystrokes, my guess is that you have a hardware problem.  Your shift key is stuck.